# count(timestamp) to return 0 DB2

Tags: count, db2, left-join, coalesce

i have been trying to find an answer but the things i found and tried does not seem to work, or i am doing something wrong.

As an example we have 2 tables:

```
Table Messages:
Int: id
Date: create_timestamp 
String: join_number

Table Map: 
String: entity_name 
String: join_number
```

I am trying to count create_timestamps and group them by Entity_name, so the query is:

```
select count(create_timestamp) as count , entity_name from Messages left join Map on Messages.join_number = Map.join_number group by entity_name
```

The query is working fine except of one problem it does not return entity with result 0 if no timestamps were found. I need it to return the entity_name and result 0 if it found nothing.

I tried query with COALESCE like this:

```
select COALESCE(count(create_timestamp), 0) as count , entity_name from Messages left join Map on Messages.join_number = Map.join_number group by entity_name
```

But it still does not return 0 values. Please keep in mind this is a DB2 Database, any comments, questions, or answers are really welcome here.

Comment: Use `Map left join Messages` instead of `Messages left join Map`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice! just tried that and still get the same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Check the following [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3380a30be981f17a9836f93499f9bca5).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out answer by Mark is correct. I did a mistake on query as i also included the condition "where timestamp > timestamp (xxxx)" which caused the query not to include those 0 results. In case someone can find it helpful, the correct query if you want to choose the timestamp is:

select count(timestamp) as count, entity_name from Map left join Messages on timestamp > timestamp('2020-01-01') and Messages.join_number = Map.join_number group by entity_name

Thanks a lot again!